# « un engin aussi imposant » vs « un engin d'aussi imposant »

Tags: prépositions

> Par quel moyen technologique pensez-vous qu'**un engin aussi imposant** puisse flotter dans le ciel ?
>
> NOT: Par quel moyen technologique pensez-vous qu'**un engin d'aussi imposant** puisse flotter dans le ciel ?

What is the rationale behind omitting « de » here? I'm not so sure when to keep « de » and when to drop it, because in the following example, on the other hand, you cannot omit « de ».

> Je n’ai jamais porté **quelque chose d'aussi élégant**.
>
> NOT: Je n’ai jamais porté **quelque chose aussi élégant**.

Comment: The **d'** must be dropped, it's not used in that case.
The only case I can see where you can use it is in questions like "Qu'est ce qu'il y a d'aussi important ?".

Comment: Seule la première phrase est correcte.

Comment: This has nothing to do with *aussi*, the acceptability contrasts are the same without it.

Comment: 'un engin aussi imposant' (adjectif seul) mais 'un engin d'aussi imposante allure' (l'adjectif est accompagné d'un nom).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Je n'ai jamais rien porté d'aussi élégant.
Je n'ai jamais rien vu d'aussi imposant.
Je n'ai jamais rien mangé d'aussi bon.
1: je constate que c'est élégant, imposant ou bon.
2: je fais une comparaison avec tout ce que j'ai porté, vu ou mangé auparavant.
Le choix des mots 'élégant, porté et bon' est effectué avant la comparaison mais arrive après dans la phrase. C'est pour coder cela que 'de' apparaît ici. 
L'information nouvelle est à gauche 'Je n'ai jamais rien porté, vu ou mangé'

Dans 'Par quel moyen pensez-vous qu'un engin aussi imposant puisse...'
'imposant' est choisi et présenté ici comme information nouvelle parmi d'autres possibles 'peu solide, lourd, encombrant...' 'imposant' n'est pas repris.

Dans 'Par quel moyen pensez-vous qu'un engin d'allure aussi imposante / d'aussi imposante allure puisse... DE apparaît ici parce que le qualificatif de l'allure est bloqué, j'ai dépassé le moment du choix du qualificatif.

Answer (score 0):

Here, *aussi* is used to qualify the adjective *imposant*. It's similar to *this* in English

> By which technical means do you think a device **this** imposing could float in the sky

To help you understand, you could omit it and say

> Par quel moyen technologique pensez-vous qu'un engin imposant puisse flotter dans le ciel ?

The first sentence follows the pattern [aussi + adjectif/adverbe](http://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-3995.php). The rationale behind omitting the *d'* is simply that it would be incorrect.